# Date Issue: CS0103: The name 'DateAdministered' does not exist in the current context

Tags: datetime, razor, datepicker, webmatrix

I'm having another date issue. My date was not saving so I decided to change the format but, now I'm getting an error.

Here is the error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'DateAdministered' does not exist in the current context

Here is my code:

```
<td><strong>Date Aministered:</strong><input type="date" id="date-of-screening" name="DateAdministered" value="@(DateAdministered !=null ? DateAministered.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "01/01/2000")"></td>
```

I have checked the name of the field to make sure it matches what's in the table and it does.  I'm not sure what the problem may be.

Comment: What's not clear from the error? It doesn't exist in the current context. Maybe you're looking for `@Model.DateAdministered`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables used in the display part of a cshtml page have to be c# variables, not database fields.  So it sounds like you might be getting your data from the database but not putting it into a variable.

Assuming you are doing something like

```
var myData = db.QuerySingle( someSQLstring);
```

Then later you can put

```
<td><strong>Date Administered:</strong><input type="date" id="date-of-screening" name="DateAdministered" value="@(myData.DateAdministered !=null ? myData.DateAministered.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "01/01/2000")"></td>
```

assuming that the query  is returning a field named DateAdministered.

Comment: I am trying to pick a date from date picker but, it's not saving in the database, therefore I was trying to add some code if it were null to see if that would make a difference but, I got an error instead.